# After updating a JS function using XMLHttpRequest and innerHTML, the old code is executed

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, innerhtml

I have a variable list of elements I'm adding event listeners to. These elements are stored in a database and are represented in HTML.
There's a PHP function retrieving those items from the database. Based on the number of items it generates a JS function which adds the listeners when the site is called, like:

```
for($x = 0; $x < $items_length; $x++) {
  echo "document.getElementById(\"elem_id".$items[$x][0]."\").
                 addEventListener(\"contextmenu\", (e) => {<some code>; e.preventDefault();});";
 }
```

If the number of items changes, I don't want the site to reload. So I run the same function in a separate PHP file with updated counter (`items_length`) and want to replace the function with the newly created one by using `innerHTML` like:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById(\"listwrapper\").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    addEventListeners();
  }
};
xmlhttp.open(\"GET\", \"<filename>.php\", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

The `responseText` is pretty much the same code as before, but with another number of elements to add eventListeners to.
This seems to work correctly, but the method call `addEventListeners();` invokes the old code, not the new one, that should be there now.

The weird thing is that HTML elements *are* shown. I added e.g. `<h3>Test</h3>` to the code which comes with the `responseText` and it shows up, like other things like that I tested.
It's just the function that is not updated. I checked the function and it always adapts to the number of items in the list.

It seems like `addEventListeners();` invokes some code in the cache or so but not the updated one in the HTML document. Is something like that possible?

EDIT: Trying to clarify

I wrote this PHP/HTML/Javascript:

```
echo "<non important HTML>
<div id=\"listwrapper\">
  <script>
    function addEventListeners() {";
      for($x = 0; $x < $items_length; $x++) {               
        echo "document.getElementById(\"label_id_".$items[$x][0]."\").addEventListener(\"contextmenu\", (e) => {alert(\"".$items[$x][0]."-".$items[$x][1]."-".$items[$x][2]."\"); e.preventDefault();});
    }
  </script>
  <div id=\"list\" class=\"container\">
    <h3>Liste</h3>
    <form action=\"".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\" method=\"post\">
      <div class=\"row\">
        <div class=\"col-75\">";
          for($x = 0; $x < $items_length; $x++) {
            // Checkbox marked as unchecked
            if($items[$x][2] == 0) {
              echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" onchange=\"updateList(this.id)\" id=\"item_id_".$items[$x][0]."\" name=\"item_id_".$items[$x][0]."\" value=\"".$items[$x][1]."\">";
            }
            // Checkbox marked as checked
            else {
              echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" onchange=\"updateList(this.id)\" id=\"item_id_".$items[$x][0]."\" name=\"item_id_".$items[$x][0]."\" value=\"".$items[$x][1]."\" checked>";
            }
            // Label showing item name
            echo "<label id=\"label_id_".$items[$x][0]."\" for=\"label_id_".$items[$x][0]."\">".$items[$x][1]."</label><br>";
          }
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"item_checked\">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<script>addEventListeners();</script>
</div>
<div class=\"container\">
  <div class=\"col-50\">
    <input type=\"button\" class=\"button\" value=\"Abgehakte runter\" onclick=\"checkedDown()\">
  </div>
  <div class=\"col-50\">
    <input type=\"button\" class=\"button_red\" value=\"Abgehakte l&ouml;schen\" onclick=\"deleteChecked()\">
  </div>
</div>
<more unimportant HTML>";
```

If the a button at the end is clicked, all checked items from the list are removed (deleteChecked()') in the database.
Another PHP file re-reads the updated database and generates the new list incl. the updated addEventListeners() function.
It basically creates the above code again.
What I am trying to do is replacing the old code with the new one which differs in the list length and the $items_length variable of the function accordingly.
It is supposed to add the EventListeners again. They are gone after this code has been replaced.
But when called, the old function (old $items_length) is called. This causes errors, of course, since the counter doesn't match the number of elements present.

I hope I could clarify this.
I'm not sure if it is possible at all to update/replace Javascript by 'injecting' it with 'innerHTML'.

Comment: What does your `addEventListeners()` function do ? Can you show the code ? What is `this.responseText` ? -- an event listener that was attached with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) stays attached until you remove it with [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). Simply adding a new one doesn't remove it.